# Load items from Room in MediaBrowserServiceCompat

Tags: android, android-room, android-livedata, android-mediasession

I'm working on an audio app using Android Architecture components. I have a service, which extends `MediaBrowserServiceCompat` and a Fragment with `MediaBrowserCompat`.

Everything works pretty well when I hard-code the songs in the service's `onLoadChildren()` method. But I have my songs stored in a Room database and would like to load them in the `onLoadChildren()` method. This is where I'm struggling.

There are 2 ways how I tried to load the songs:

1)
**SongsDAO:**

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM songs ORDER BY name COLLATE UNICODE ASC")
List<Song> getSongs();
```

**Service:**

```
 @Override
 public void onLoadChildren(@NonNull String parentId, @NonNull Result<List<MediaBrowserCompat.MediaItem>> result) {
     result.detach();
     songsRepository = new SongsRepository(getApplication());
     List<Song> songs = songsRepository.getSongs();

     List<MediaBrowserCompat.MediaItem> mediaItems = convertToMediaItems(songs);
     result.sendResult(mediaItems);
 }
```

In this way, I get an error, that Room query was executed on main thread. One possible way is probably to encapsulate the method into AsyncTask, but I believe there are better ways.

2)
**SongsDAO:**

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM songs ORDER BY name COLLATE UNICODE ASC")
LiveData<List<Song>> getSongs();
```

**Service:**

```
 @Override
 public void onLoadChildren(@NonNull String parentId, @NonNull Result<List<MediaBrowserCompat.MediaItem>> result) {
     result.detach();
     songsRepository = new SongsRepository(getApplication());
     LiveData<List<Song>> songs = songsRepository.getSongs();

     songs.observe(???, (Observer<List<Song>>) songs1 -> {
        List<MediaBrowserCompat.MediaItem> mediaItems = mapToMediaItems(songs1);
        result.sendResult(mediaItems);
    });
 }
```

In this way, I don't know how process the LiveData songs. They cannot be iterated in loop and probably observed neither as there is nothing which can be used as LifecycleOwner (first parameter of the observe method).

I couldn't find any best practice on how to solve this use case. I would like to have a SPOT (single point of truth) class, which would contain all songs in the app. It could be then used in the service to provide data to app's UI (RecyclerView) as well as to other apps (Android Auto). I would like to have access to these songs from anywhere in the app - when I add a new song or delete any from the Room database, the list should be updated automatically.

How do you recommend to implement something like this? Thanks in advance for any suggestion.

Comment: Did you end up with a satisfying solution? Another related question is when do you call notifyChildrenChanged.

Answer (score 0):

One of the solutions is using [observeForever](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/LiveData#observeforever) (which does not require lifecycle owner as a param) instead of `observe`. Moreover, I recommed to remove created observer inside `onDestroy` lifecycle method of used `Service` using [removeobserver](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/LiveData.html#removeobserver) for avoiding memory leaks.